# Expectation using R

Tags: r

I just started using R and I have 5 files(each file has only one column) of data with 227 observations in total. I have to find E(X) and E(X^2). I found E(X) by summing up all the values and dividing it by 227. I also need to find E(X^2) but I don't know how to loop through the 5 files and get each individual value and square it.

I have code for loading the files and that is my code for finding the mean:

```
    mydataset1 = read_csv("file1.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset2 = read_csv("file2.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset3 = read_csv("file3.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset4 = read_csv("file4.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset5 = read_csv("file5.txt", col_names = FALSE)

    sum1 <- sum(mydataset1) 
    sum2 <- sum(mydataset2) 
    sum3 <- sum(mydataset3)
    sum4 <- sum(mydataset4)
    sum5 <- sum(mydataset5)

    sumAll <- sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5

    mean <- sumAll / 227
```

Comment: For clarity, you say *"file"* but really it's just a variable in R, right? (Whether you read it from a file or not is immaterial for the sake of doing math on it.)

Comment: BTW: in R, a lot of operations can work on a whole vector at a time. So `E(x)` is (as you know) just `sum(x)/length(x)`, and `E(x^2)` is just `sum(x^2)/length(x)`, so `x^2` squares each of the elements within `x` independently, and very efficiently/quickly. In learning R, this is likely one of the biggest (and hardest for newer programmers) payoffs to learn and use early. Not everything can work like this, but when it can, doing anything else can be punishing in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

We can get all the datasets in a `list` with `mget` based on the `pattern` of object names get the `sum` from the `list` elements into a `vector` and then get the `sum` of that vector divided by 227

```
sum(sapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^mydataset\\d+$')), sum))/227
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply square the variable

```r
    mydataset1 = read_csv("file1.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset2 = read_csv("file2.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset3 = read_csv("file3.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset4 = read_csv("file4.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset5 = read_csv("file5.txt", col_names = FALSE)

    sum1 <- sum(mydataset1 ^ 2) 
    sum2 <- sum(mydataset2 ^ 2) 
    sum3 <- sum(mydataset3 ^ 2)
    sum4 <- sum(mydataset4 ^ 2)
    sum5 <- sum(mydataset5 ^ 2)
```

The rest of your code will be the same

Answer (score 0):

@Hugo actually answers the simple question of how do you square a variable in R and then do an operation on it. I think we all assume you don't really want to create a new variable that is X1 squared (but you could do that if you wanted).

I'm going to suggest maybe a more beginner solution than some of the above if what you are doing is trying to learn the basics of R.

```
    mydataset1 = read_csv("file1.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset2 = read_csv("file2.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset3 = read_csv("file3.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset4 = read_csv("file4.txt", col_names = FALSE)
    mydataset5 = read_csv("file5.txt", col_names = FALSE)

combined <- rbind(mydataset1, mydataset2, mydataset3, mydataset4, mydataset5)
sum(combined$X1)/nrow(combined)
sum(combined$X1^2)/nrow(combined)
```

In this solution you are still reading the individual files and type out their names, and as shown in other answers there are lots of neat ways to do that automatically. This will always work.

Here what I'm doing is combining the data frames/ tibbles using the base rbind() function. It does what it sounds like, binds the data frames together.

Then I am doing the calculation, but instead of assuming that I know the number of rows, I'm getting it from the data.  (If you have missing data that becomes a little more tricky but you will learn that soon enough.)
Also note that I am specifying the actual variable that you want. That is so you have a model for a situation in the future when you have multiple variables in your data frame.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try a base R code like below

```
sum(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "mydataset\\d+"))))/227
```

---

Mathematically, `sumAll` is the sum of all data from `mydataset1` to `mydataset5`, In this sense, you can gather them via `unlist` and then sum them up before being divided by `227`.